# Conditional Formatting for Multiple Criteria

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I'm currently having trouble with conditional formatting for 3+ conditions.

What I want to do is that if 3 or more criteria are matched (or not matched, for a cell to turn a certain color.

Example:

There are multiple teams, their project priority, and the revenue they've made. I want to turn column C cells green or red based on A) the priority is "Medium" B) the team is "Korea Design" C) Green if $10K or above revenue, red if below $10K revenue. So if it matches A,B,C criteria, then the revenue column(C) will turn Green; alternatively if it matches A,B but not C (the revenue goal), then it will turn red.

*So first filtering that it is A and B, and then determining green or red depending on the revenue.

Thank you!

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1McMvsXVNWEQ1XzGdCY4HbXz5QKoxTeYiBdMLt-02pa0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

green:

```
=(A2="Korea Design")*(B2="Medium")*(C2>=10000)
```

red:

```
=(A2="Korea Design")*(B2="Medium")*(C2<10000)
```

[image]